# What's the right way to implement producer/consumer w/ SQLite3?

Tags: php, sqlite

How do I occasionally write to a sqlite database which has frequent readers?  I'm using PHP, but that doesn't really matter.  I understand that the query() will return `SQLITE_BUSY`, and I can try again, and that I can call `busyTimeout` to help, but I'm hoping there's a built-in way to tell the database to wait on its own.  Right now, I'm using:

```
function wait_query_db($db, $query) {
    do {
        $db->busyTimeout(1000);
        $result = @$db->query($query);
    } while ($db->lastErrorCode() == SQLITE_BUSY);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Really that's all DMS run with parameters defined by DBA

Comment: Frequent readers or writers? Because in SQLite you can have theoretically an unlimited # of readers. Your DB should get locked during writes, for writes

Comment: "How do I occasionally write to a sqlite database which has frequent readers?"  Basically, the writes are infrequent, but may take several minutes, but the reads are frequent and very quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`busyTimeout` (or the equivalent `PRAGMA busy_timeout`) *is* the built-in way to tell the database to wait.

If you want to wait longer, you should use a larger timeout.

If your PHP is new enough that you have at least SQLite 3.7, and if your database is not being accessed through a network file system, you should consider enabling [write-ahead logging](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html), which prevents readers and writers from blocking each other.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "builtin" way. Increase busy timeout. You can set it to a connection itself by executing:

```
PRAGMA busy_timeout = milliseconds
```

(available since SQLite 3.7.15)

Comment: It looks like `PRAGMA busy_timeout = 1000;` is the same as `$db->busyTimeout(1000);`.  If that's the case, then I would only need to call it once after opening the database, right?  And can remove it from my loop?

Comment: You need to call it only once regardless of which form you use.

Comment: Yes, it's the same you can certainly remove setting timeout from loop.